# Problems Conway's Game of Life Logic

Tags: java

I've been trying to get this game of life running properly for hours now and for some reason I just cant, Its something either in the runLife() or countNeighbors() class. The issue isn't syntactical but there is some logical error that when i input a test case such as

```
 ..*..
 ..*..
 ..*..
```

I get

```
 .....
 .***.
 .....
```

and then instead of returning to

```
 ..*..
 ..*..
 ..*..
```

it becomes

```
 ..**.
 .*.*.
 .....
```

My code is:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.*;
 public class GameOfLife
 {
//variables used, 24 and 80 are the default size.
private int rows = 24;
private int cols = 80;
private String [][] current = new String[rows][cols];
private String [][] next = new String[rows][cols];
// primary constructor that takes in 2 integers and sets the rows and cols to them
public GameOfLife(int r, int c)
{
    rows = r;
    cols = c;
    if(r<0){ 
        rows = rows * -1;
    }
    if(c<0){ 
        cols = cols * -1;
    }
    if (r==0||c==0){
        System.err.print("Incorrect parameters, setting to default");
        rows = 24;
        cols = 80;
    }
    for (int x = 0; x <= rows - 1; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y <= cols - 1; y++){
            int q = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            if(q%2 == 0){
                current[x][y]="dead";
            }
            else{
                current[x][y]="alive";}
        }
    }
}
// secondary constructor that takes in no parameters
public GameOfLife()
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= rows - 1; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y <= cols - 1; y++){
            int r = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            if(r%2 == 0){
                current[x][y]="dead";
            }
            else{
                current[x][y]="alive";}
        }
    }
}

//constructor that takes in a string double array in the graphical style as the parameter to make as the first generation
public GameOfLife(String[][] s){
    rows = s.length;
    cols = s[0].length;
    for (int x = 0; x <= rows - 1; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y <= cols - 1; y++){
            if (s[x][y].equals("*")){
                current[x][y]="alive";}
            else {current[x][y]="dead";}
        }
    }
}

//uses the game rules to run the game and progress to the next generation
public void runLife(){
    //loops and checks neighbors to abide by the rules of the game
    for (int x = 0; x <= rows - 1; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y <= cols - 1; y++){
            //checks the alive rules for each one
            int p=countNeighbors(x,y);
            if(p<=1){next[x][y]="dead";}
            if(p==2){
                if(current[x][y].equals("alive")){
                    next[x][y]="alive";}
                else{next[x][y]="dead";}}
            if(p==3){next[x][y]="alive";}
            if(p>3){next[x][y]="dead";}
        }
    }
    current = next;
}
//counts the neighbors of a specified location
public int countNeighbors(int row, int col){
    int q=0;
    for ( int x = row -1; x <= row + 1 ; x++)
    {
        for (int y = col -1 ; y <= col + 1 ; y++)
        {
            boolean go=true;
            if((x < 0 || y < 0)){go=false;}
            if(x>=rows){go=false;}
            if(y>=cols){go=false;}
            if ((x == row) && (y==col)){ go=false;}
            if(go==true){if(current[x][y].equals("alive")){q++;}}

        }
    }
    return q;
 }
//makes the array into a string of graphics that is a good visualization of the code in work
public String toGraphic(){
    String s = "";
    for(int x = 0; x <= rows - 1; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y <= cols - 1; y++){
            if(current[x][y].equals("alive")){
                s=s+"*";
            }
            else{
                s=s+" ";}
        }
        s= s+"\n";
    }
    return s;
}
//continuously prints out the toGraphic option to visualise what happens every pass
public void animate(int t, int o){
    //checking for incorrect parameters
    if(t<0){ 
        t = t * -1;
    }
    if(o<0){ 
        o = o * -1;
    }
    if(o==0){ 
        System.err.print("You have selected no amount");
    }
    //looping the toGraphic method a set amount of times
    int q=0;
    while(q<=t){
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long end = 0;
        System.out.println(toGraphic());
        while ((end-start)<=o){
            end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        q++;
        runLife();
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`runLife` fills `next` based on `current`, which works for the first generation.  But for each future generation, you need to copy what is in `next` back into `current`.

The statement `current = next` makes them the same array, as opposed to 2 distinct arrays with the same contents.